# Llave foranea de tipo SERIAL - mySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

En la tabla "Detalles de orden" (ordCodigo) y (prodCodigo) son llaves primarias pero a la vez foraneas (ye hice esto alguna vez) pero el problema aqui es que el tipo de dato es SERIAL.

Esto puede hacer?
Como?

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos, pues usaste la etiqueta de dos

Comment: Estoy usando mySQL

Comment: osea tu pregunta es si se pueden hacer llaves foráneas con datos de tipo `SERIAL`?

Comment: Si.
Es que la PK de (ordenes) es un SERIAL
Y la PK de (productos) es un SERIAL
y como (detalles de ordene) depende  de las dos antes mencionadas.
1) una tabla no puede tener mas de un dato de tipo SERIAL
2) ordCodigo y proCodigo de (detalles de orden) les puse INT pero da error porque no concuerdan con el tipo de dato de la tabla maestra

Comment: Creo que ya lo voy a solucionar en lugar de usar SERIAL.
Voy a hacer por ejemplo: id int auto_increment

Comment: espero la respuesta te sirva

Comment: Justamente iba a preguntarte **¿cuál es el motivo por el que quieres usar `SERIAL`?**. Una de las cosas que tienes que tomar en cuenta es que [`SERIAL` es un *alias*  del tipo de dato `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) por tanto debes ser consciente que un campo `SERIAL` es realmente del tipo `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE` y que además [según respuesta a esta pregunta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183719), al usarlo se crean dos índices en la tabla para el mismo campo.

Comment: Además, la teoría de base de datos dicta determinadas pautas, pero en tu diagrama a menos que la columna prodCodigo no sea lo que yo interpreto, no creo deba ser de tipo serial. Puedes tener llaves primarias de tipo serial, pero prodCodigo a mi entender código del producto no.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación de

- [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)
- [MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)

Un dato de tipo serial posee las siguientes características

- `BIGINT`
- `UNSIGNED`
- `NOT NULL`
- `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- `UNIQUE`

Lo cual implica que si deseas crear una serie de tablas donde sus llaves primarias y foráneas sean de tipo `SERIAL` como las que a continuación se muestran

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Y una segunda tabla de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  id SERIAL,
  cantidad INT,
  usuario_id SERIAL,
  CONSTRAINT posts_usuarios FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id)
);
```

Se obtendrá un resultado de error como el siguiente

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Que nos identifica un error con la creación de la segunda tabla, pues si bien la PK `id` es serial la FK que es `usuario_id` al ser también serial entra en conflicto pues intenta crear un valor `AUTO_INCREMENT` de la cual solo debe existir una y que sea declarada como la `PK` de dicha tabla.

Tampoco podrás declarar a la FK `usuario_id` de un tipo distinto a `INT` o `BIGINT` pues entraría en conflicto por los tipos de datos y características que posee `SERIAL` mencionadas ya mas arriba.

En conclusión deberías estar usando algún tipo de dato `INT` o `BIGINT` de manera explícita para la declaración de tus llaves primarias `PK` y así mismo de tus llaves foráneas `FK`